# Make all subfolders with name "abc" and their contents writeable - Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

**Description:**

In windows if you right click a folder/file there is a checkbox read-only, **I want a command to remove that tick from the checkbox.**

**A bit more complex:**

I want **a command** to get all subfolders in a folder (A) with name abc, and remove that 'read-only' tick from them and all of their contents

I have have found bits of this in other questions but without any luck of combining them successfully

**Structure example:**

```
+---A
|   +---B
|   |   +---abc
|   |   |   |   file1.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file2.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file3.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file4.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file4.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   +---d
|   |   |   |   |   file1.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   |   file2.txt <-- apply here ---
|   +---e
|   |   +---f
|   |   +---abc
|   |   |   |   file1.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file2.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file3.txt <-- apply here ---
|   |   |   |   file4.txt <-- apply here ---

etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it.

```
$folder = 'c:\test'
$MatchingSubfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory 'abc' -Recurse
    Foreach ($item in $MatchingSubfolders) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $item.FullName -File -Recurse | % {Set-ItemProperty $_.FullName -name IsReadOnly -value $false}
    }
```

> ## **[Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-6)**
>
> ### **Description**
>
> The `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet changes the value of the property of the
>   specified item. You can use the cmdlet to establish or change the
>   properties of items. For example, you can use `Set-ItemProperty` to set
>   the value of the IsReadOnly property of a file object to `$True`.
>
> You also use `Set-ItemProperty` to create and change registry values and
>   data. For example, you can add a new registry entry to a key and
>   establish or change its value.
>
> `Set-ItemProperty -Path C:\GroupFiles\final.doc -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true`

Comment: Have to add conditional way on the parent directory name

Comment: Tested and working fine thank you very much sir, also made the $folder as an argument, but that wasn't in the question so you get full marks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can using this to find show all files in directory :

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd, [string[]]$exclude) 
{ 
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if ($exclude | Where {$item -like $_}) { continue }

        if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container) 
        {
            $item 
            GetFiles $item.FullName $exclude
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $item 
        }
    } 
}
```

And set the isReadOnly value off file when it's on parent directory with they name equal (-eq) 'abc'

Soo you can write a possible function like this :

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd, [string[]]$exclude) 
{ 
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if ($exclude | Where {$item -like $_}) { continue }

        if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container) 
        {
            # directory
            $item 
            GetFiles $item.FullName $exclude
        } 
        else 
        { 
            # file 
            if($item.Parent.Name -eq "abc"){
                # parent directory was named abc 
                # change isReadOnly value to false
                # $item.isreadonly = $false;
                Set-ItemProperty $item.FullName -name IsReadOnly -value $false
            }
            $item
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Windows [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
rem /* Find sub-directories named `abc` and loop through them;
rem    the root directory, hence the current one, is expected not to match: */
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "abc"') do (
    rem // Return all files in the currently iterated sub-directory:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%%D\*.*"') do (
        rem // Do the attribute change at this point:
        attrib -R "%%F"
    )
)
```

To use that code in a Windows [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) command line directly, you have to change it (no remarks):

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "abc"') do @for /F "delims= eol=|" %F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%D\*.*"') do @attrib -R "%%F"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that PowerShell is a good way to go. That does not mean that the old ways stop working.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %d IN ('DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\test" 2^>NUL') DO (
    IF /I "%~nxd" == "abc" (ATTRIB -R "%~d" & ATTRIB -R "%~d\*")
)
```